# Is such a crypto-system available?

Tags: encryption

$E(k_1, pt) = c_1, E(k_2, c_1) = c_2, D(k_{new}, c_2) = pt$, where $k_{new} = f(k_1, k_2).$ Sharing $k_{new}$ and $k_2$ should reveal no information about $k_1$.

Clarifications:

1. Being able to decrypt the ciphertext $c_2$ knowing only $k_{new}$ is the first desired property of the system
2. One cannot derive $k_1$ knowing both $k_{new}$ and $k_2$.
3. One cannot easily derive $k_1$ knowing other pairs $k_2'$ and $k_{new}'$. See @poncho's comments.

$D(k_{new}, c_2) = pt$ or $E(k_{new}, c_2) = pt$ doesn't matter as long as you recover the plaintext.

Real world example to clarify things even more:

1. Alice has a very large database which it chooses to store at Eve's site. Because Alice doesn't want Eve to read the data, nor doesn't she know in advance which data will be shared with whom, she encrypts all the records with a single key ($k_1$).
2. Now Bob requests access to some specific information. Bob and Alice know each other so Alice gives him access to that subset. However Alice wants to do that efficiently. Also Alice doesn't want Bob to be able to read anything else except the shared subset. Therefore she cannot: a) Decrypt the shared subset at Eve's site and then re-encrypt with a different key (this would expose all the database contents to Eve), b) Retrieve the data from Eve, decrypt, re-encrypt and store back data at Eve's site - this implies a round-trip delay which is prohibitively expensive.

Thus Alice needs a cryptosystem which would allow re-encrypting the data directly at Eve's site, however Eve shouldn't be able to read any plain text (nor the one shared with Bob, nor the rest of the database records). Sharing the decryption key ($k_{new}$) is done through a direct channel between Alice and Bob (e.g. using Diffie-Hellman).

The "cryptosystem" stated in the question is just a way I saw that happening. Note that $k_1$ shouldn't become known to Bob (e.g. if Bob colludes with Eve or other people with whom Alice shares (possibly different sets of) data).

Comment: Knowledge of $k_{new}$ and $k_2$ will allow the decryption of any plaintext encrypted by $k_1$; what further information about $k_1$ do you want to be certain isn't revealed?

Comment: The value of k1

Comment: Typically, keys don't have any intrinsic value; the only reason we would prefer that people don't learn them is because of the ability that those keys would confer (for example, being able to decrypt traffic).  Revealing knew and k2 allows people to decrypt; what further ability would you prefer people not to have?

Comment: Suppose I encrypt a large text with $k_1$. Now I want to share a small portion of that text by encrypting it with $k_2$. Now I can share $k_{new}$ with Alice. Alice can decrypt only the portion she is supposed to see.

Comment: The property you ask for would imply that your cipher is a group, which for block ciphers one tries to avoid since double/triple encryption wouldn't be stronger than a single encryption (google for "DES is not a group").

Comment: The point is not to make the encryption stronger, the point is to enable a third party see only a subset of the data with minimal overhead (avoiding the naive scenario where one has to decrypt c1, encrypt with k2 and then just share k2).

Comment: @jug Searching for "DES is not a group" I gradually found proxy re-encryption which seems like something I am looking for.

Comment: Is the desired cryptosystem symmetric, or asymmetric? The later would imply that $k_1$ and $k_2$ each have a _public_ component, which knowledge is enough to evaluate $x\mapsto E(k_1,x)$ and $x\mapsto E(k_2,x)$.

Comment: It doesn't matter for me as long as it satisfies the properties specified in the question. The originator of the data has key k1, Alice has key k_new. Even if Alice finds k2 or any other pairs (k2', k_new') she shouldn't be able to compute k1.

Comment: [This earlier question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5575/two-step-encryption) looks remarkably similar.  Is that just a coincidence, or is there some connection I'm missing?

Comment: Ah! No requirement for asymmetric crypto; it is no issue that whoever is able to evaluate $x\mapsto E(k_1,x)$ may safely evaluate the reverse function $y\mapsto D(k_1,y)$; same for $k_2$. Now, is it allowable that some authority is involved in the establishment of some of the (possibly public) parameters common to $k_1$ and $k_2$? And that this authority holds a secret necessary to evaluate $f()$, which disclosure would allow recovering (an equivalent of) $k_1$ from $k_2$ and $k_{new}$, as in my understanding of [this interesting answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/6246/555)?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen yes the questions seem to be identical, except mine has a "non-theoretical" use case :) and there is no requirement on the type of cryto-system used.

Comment: @fgrieu there is no need in a trusted authority. Alice generated k1, k2 and computes k_new as a function of k1 and k2. It is ok if k_new is independent of k1 and k2 but I can't imagine something like this is possible (after all c2 is some sort of a function of k1 and k2). Bob needs only k_new to recover the original plaintext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with RSA where k1 and k2 are encryption keys and f is  multiplication modulo the totient of the public modulus.
The last property, that knowledge of other pairs $k_2'$ and $k_{new}'$ does not reveal $k_1$ is satisfied by using a different modulus for each pair generated.

Comment: You mean that f is the inverse of the multiplication of k1 and k2.  In any case, this has a subtle problem; if someone learns k2, f(k1, k2), k3, f(k1, k3), they can deduce k1.  Does this matter?  Well, we can't tell from the question.

Comment: Doesn't work. 1) k_new would be an encryption key, not a decryption key 2) f is invertable. So you can calculate k1 = k_new/k2.

Comment: @CodesInChaos 1)No. My definition of f is correct because the post specifies D(k_new,c2)=pt not E(k_new,c2)=pt. Presumably the Decryption function magically obtains the decryption exponent from k_new! 2)Give me an example of inverting f which is not equivalent to factoring the modulus and hence breaking RSA.

Comment: @poncho I guess I could have specified that D=E and then f is the inverse as you said.

Comment: Checking my understanding of the suggested solution: $pt^{k_1} = c_1, c_1^{k_2} = c_2, k_{new} = (k_1 * k_2)^{-1} mod(\phi(N))$. $pt = c_2^{k_{new}} = pt^{k_1 * k_2 *(k_1 * k_2)^{-1}}$ Is that right?

Comment: @poncho regarding your comment on k1, k2, k3. How one can deduce k1?

Comment: @Eugen: the quick version (to fit within a comment) is: $k_2 * F(k_1, k_2) = k_3 * F(k_1, k_3) (\bmod \phi(N))$ (actually, $\bmod \lambda(N) = lcm(p-1, q-1)$; that detail doesn't modify the argument), and hence if $k_2 * F(k_1, k_2) - k_3 * F(k_1, k_3)$ is not zero (which is quite likely), it's a multiple of $\lambda(N)$; knowledge of such a multiple is enough to allow you to factor $N$ efficiently, and with that, you can recompute $k_1$ from $k_2$ and $F(k_1, k_2)$

Comment: @Eugen: that quick version was for the case that $F(k_1, k_2) = (k_1 \cdot k_2)^{-1}$; for Barack's original suggestion $F(k_1, k_2) = (k_1 \cdot k_2)$, you'd use $k_2 \cdot F(k_1, k_3) - k_3 \cdot F(k_1, k_2)$ instead; exact same reasoning would apply.

Comment: @Eugen I must object to the goalpost shifting! I spent a fair amount of time checking that my solution solved your problem and then updating it after you changed the question once. Now you've changed it completely and it seems likely Poncho's answer will be better. It would have been fairer to accept my answer and then ask a new question with the "real" problem you were trying to solve all along!

Comment: @BarackObama I think the conditions haven't changed that much from the original (a non-negligible change is that I haven't thought that alternative k2' k_new' pairs might reveal original k1). The use case description is just an example to help other readers understand the abstract description, no new requirements are introduced there. However it may be, I am thankful to all people considering this post worth spending their time, regardless of the actual contributions. By the way using different modulus for different pairs seems to solve the (k2', k_new') problem.

Comment: @poncho Could you point out to a paper that explains the efficiency of the factorization in case same modulus is reused for multiple pairs?

Comment: @Eugen: I don't know any specific paper that specifically addresses the efficiency; however if $n = \log_2 N$ is the size of the modulus, then it can be done in $O(n^3)$ probabilistic time; about as much time as a handful of RSA operations,

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I believe that there is a solution, but it follows a different strategy than your proposed approach.  The problem with your approach is that if Eve (with $k_{new}$) and Bob (with $k_2$) collude, there's nothing stopping them from reading the entire text (and not just the part that Alice wants Bob to read).

Instead, consider that Alice divides up the plaintext into a series of blocks; she also selects a master key (H1), and creates a tree of keys as:

```
               H1
        /-----/ \------\
       /                \
     H2                  H3
   /    \              /   \
  H4     H5           H6    H7
 / \    /  \         / \   /  \
H8 H9  H10 H11    H12 H13 H14 H15
```

For each internal node $H_i$, you would use some hash function to generate the two child nodes $H_{2i}$ and $H_{2i+1}$:

$H_{2i} = F(H_i)$

$H_{2i+1} = G(H_i)$

Where both $F$ and $G$ are noninvertible functions.

You would use the values in the leaf nodes to encrypt the successive blocks (so in the example, the first block would be encrypted using H8, the second block would be encrypted using H9, etc.

If the entire database consists of $N$ blocks, this would take a depth $\log_2(N)$ tree.

Now, when Alice decided to reveal a portion of the plaintext to Bob, she would just reveal the internal nodes that would allow Bob to recompute the keys used to encrypt those sections.  For example, if Alice wanted to reveal the sections protected by H10 through H14, all she would need to reveal would be H5 (which allows Bob to recompute H10 and H11), H6 (which allows Bob to recompute H12 and H13) and H14.  In general, to reveal a section of $M$ consecutive blocks, Alice needs to reveal at most $O(\log(M))$ internal nodes.

Now, Bob only gets the data Alice has decided to reveal; and even if a group of Bobs (and Eve) collude, they can only read what Alice has revealed to one of the Bobs.

Comment: The question to which this is a good answer is quite far away from the initial question to which my answer was perfectly correct. Could you separate this into two questions for which yours would be the answer to one of them and mine the other?

Comment: Yes, it's a ways from how the initial question was phrased.  However, whether it's a good answer really depends on what Eugen is actually interested in.  If he has an academic interest in this type of cipher (and gave his Real World example as a way it might be used), it's off topic.  However, if his Real World Example is the problem he is really interested in (and he thought that a cipher as he described might solve it), well, he needs to be told that such a cipher doesn't have the security properties he wants, and here is a better method that does.

Comment: @poncho The solution satisfies the requirements although I would like to share my thoughts on its deficiencies (btw. Bob knows k_new and Eve knows k2). First is the storage overhead needed to store the hash tree. With the Barack Obama's solution I have to store k_new (and modulus) only for the portions I share (although public key crypto is much slower than symmetric encryption). If new data is added there is a problem again (if I shared H8 now Bob would know also H16, H17, right?). Regarding my interests: they are mixed indeed, but solving the real example has a bigger priority for me.

Comment: @Eugen: as for the amount of storage needed, well, just storing H1 will allow you to recompute the tree as needed with $O(\log N)$ hash operations.  If it becomes necessary to append data, well, you don't want to reuse external nodes as internal; you can extend the solution to make multiple trees (with each tree being bigger; this preserves the $O(\log N)$ scaling properties).  One problem happens if Alice needs to update database; if she's revealed the key for a block, Bob can decrypt that block even after it has been updated.  I'm not sure how to work around that.

Comment: @poncho Regarding the storage you are right: its either storing or recomputing it every time you need to retrieve/share some data. Making new trees requires recomputing not only the hashes but re-encrypting the database on each insertion :). I hope it is understood that this is just an open discussion. I am not nitpicking or something like that.

Comment: @poncho Good answer BTW! You say that with my solution, if Eve and Bob collude then they can read the entire text. I can't work out what assumptions you must be making for this to be true, but yet for the scheme not to be rejected outright due to the absence of a selective disclosure property. In other words, how must the system be set up for collusion to be of any benefit?